# Enqueue JS and jQuery to head of specific wordpress pages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm looking to add jQuery function to the head of specific pages on WordPress. It's to allow accordions to be closed after being opened.

I only require to use it on -> WooCommerce Single Product pages, FAQ page and Contact us page.

- Page Slugs = ('faqs','contact')
- is_singular('product') for Single Product Page

Action added to `functions.php` - It saves successfully but doesn't work. Not sure what I've done wrong.

```
function my_closeaccordionscript() {
    if( is_page( array( 'faqs','contact') ) ){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'toggle-script', '/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
    if(is_singular('product')){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'toggle-script', '/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_closeaccordionscript' );
```

This is the file content of '`accordiontoggle.js`' which is saved in child theme directory... `wp-content/themes/child-theme/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js`

EDIT:

The answer was to use `get_theme_file_uri()`

```
{wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js'), array(jquery), '1.0.0', true );}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack member [Ruvee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15040627/ruvee) provided great assistance with this problem, but his answer / comments seem to have disappeared.

We tried various things, but I finally got it to work by adding `get_theme_file_uri()`to the file source.

```
{wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js'), array(jquery), '1.0.0', true );}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is correct for selectively loading the script, and the use of two IF statements is proper control flow.

You need to add jQuery as a dependancy when enqueueing a jQuery script with wp_enqueue_script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'toggle-script', '/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

Typically a jQuery script must be wrapped with:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code goes here
    });
 });
```

Or (use this because you are manipulating images):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on('load', function () {
    // Your code goes here
    });
});
```

This is important because `wp_enqueue_scripts` inserts the script into the document `<head>` which is loaded first. Without waiting for `document ready` or `window load` event, you are selecting elements with jQuery that don't exist yet.

From [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) docs:

'A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.'

Answer (score 1):

It could be that it's located in the child theme. In order to load a script on the frontend that's located in a child theme folder you can  use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri().` If the script isn't located in the header of the file you can you use. `add_action('wp_head','my_closeaccordionscript');`

`function my_closeaccordionscript() {  if( is_page( array( 'faqs','contact') ) ){ wp_enqueue_script( 'toggle-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/accordiontoggle.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); } if(is_singular('product')){ wp_enqueue_script( 'toggle-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . /assets/js/accordiontoggle.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); }} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_closeaccordionscript' );`